# Why doesn't the iterator go through the first while?

Tags: java, java-8, iterator

I'm trying to find the same lines in the lists and combine them into groups.(This is similar to the finding of non-sets).

A1;B1;C1

A2;B2;C2
...

Find a set of unique strings and divide it into disjoint groups by the following criteria:
If two rows have matching non-empty values in one or more columns, they belong to the same group.

111;123;222

200;123;100

300;;100

all belong to the same group, since the first two rows have the same value 123 in the second column, and the last two have the same value 100 in the third column.

```
private static Map<String, List<List<String>>> findGroupe1(List<List<String>> 
lines)
{
    Map<String, List<List<String>>> map=new HashMap<>();
    ListIterator listIterator=lines.listIterator();
    int count=0;
    while (listIterator.hasNext()){
        List<String>list1= (List<String>) listIterator.next();
        count++;
        map.put("Group :"+count,new ArrayList<>());
        map.get("Group :"+count).add(list1);
        while (listIterator.hasNext())
        {
            List<String>list2= (List<String>) listIterator.next();
            if(isAnyFieldMatches(list1,list2)&&list1!=list2)
            {
                map.get("Group :"+count).add(list2);
                listIterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
    return  map;
}

          private static boolean isAnyFieldMatches(List<String> list1,List<String> list2)
            {   boolean b=false;
                for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0;j<list2.size();j++)
                    {
                        if(list1.get(i).equals(list2.get(j))) {                          
                            b = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return b;
            }
```

I find groups,but not all of them,because the iterator, after passing in the second while, goes to the first one and exits it.For example:

```
List<List<String>> lines=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String>list1=new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("A");
    list1.add("B2");
    list1.add("C3");
    List<String>list2=new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add("C1");
    list2.add("B2");
    list2.add("K3");
    List<String>list3=new ArrayList<>();
    list3.add("D1");
    list3.add("B2");
    list3.add("C3");
    List<String>list4=new ArrayList<>();
    list4.add("X1");
    list4.add("R2");
    list4.add("Y3");
    lines.add(list1);lines.add(list2); lines.add(list3); lines.add(list4);

    Map<String, List<List<String>>> map=findGroupe1(lines);
    System.out.println(map.toString());
```

list 4 does not fall into a separate group,how do I fix it?

Comment: You have `Lists`, so maybe instead of `iterators`, just use a normal `for` loop and use the `get` method of the `List interface`. Is there a specific reason you are using `iterators`?

Comment: I am removing items from the list and a normal loop will not provide a pass through all the items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that with `iterator.next()` you advance the cursor to the next element, so in your 2nd (=inner) while loop you advance the cursor of the iterator to the end of the list, so when your second while loop exits and the code comes back to the outer while loop, the iterator is already at the end of the list.

I would use two separate iterators, one for
"go through every line" and a second one for "check every other line" (and this second iterator has to be initialized again for each element of the first iterator.

So something like

```
private static Map<String, List<List<String>>> findGroupe1(List<List<String>> lines) {
    ListIterator<List<String>> outerIterator = lines.listIterator();
    while (outerIterator.hasNext()) {
        List<String> currentLine = outerIterator.next();
        ListIterator<List<String>> innerIterator = lines.listIterator();

        while (innerIterator.hasNext()) {
            List<String> lineToCheck = innerIterator.next();
            System.out.println(lineToCheck);
            //check currentLine with lineToCheck
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Btw, if not required I would definitely NOT use iterators for this kind of problem.

Comment: What is better to use instead of an iterator?

Comment: When using two iterators, I get-ConcurrentModificationException.

Comment: If you are relatively new to java, start with "normal" for loops like shown here https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_for_loop.asp 
  for (int i = 0; i<list.size();i++) ... and so on

Comment: For the ConcurrentModificationException take a look at https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-resolve-the-javautilconcurrentmodificationexception  it basically means that you change the list during the time you "iterate" over the list.

Comment: Thank you, I will use for () instead of the first while.Is there an alternative to ArrayList in Concurrent Collections?

Comment: I don't think you will need a >>Concurrent<< collection (ArrayList btw. is not concurrent, you would need to use something like https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html)... the "simple" ArrayList should do absolutely fine for your problem